# Why MYSQL IN keyword not considering NULL values

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am using the following query:

```
select count(*) from Table1 where CurrentDateTime>'2012-05-28 15:34:02.403504' and Error not in ('Timeout','Connection Error');
```

Surprisingly, this statement doesnot include the rows having Error value as NULL.My intention is to filter only rows with Error value as 'Timeout' (or) 'Connection Error'. I need to give an additional condition( OR Error is NULL) to retrieve the correct result.

Why is MYSQL filtering out results with NULL values?
I thought that IN keyword would return a boolean result (1/0) and now i understand that some MYSQL keywords doesnt return boolean values,it might return NULL too....but Why is it treating NULL as special?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This :

```
Error not in ('Timeout','Connection Error');
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
Error <> 'TimeOut' AND Error <> 'Connection Error'
```

Rules about null comparison applies to IN too. So if the value of Error is NULL, the database can't make the expression true.

To fix, you could do this:

```
COALESCE(Error,'') not in ('Timeout','Connection Error');
```

Or better yet:

```
Error IS NULL OR Error not in ('Timeout','Connection Error');
```

Or more better yet:

```
 CASE WHEN Error IS NULL THEN 1
 ELSE Error not in ('Timeout','Connection Error') THEN 1
 END = 1
```

`OR` doesn't short-circuit, CASE can somehow short-circuit your query

---

Perhaps a concrete example could illustrate why `NULL NOT IN expression` returns nothing:

Given this data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d5da/11

```
create table tbl
(
  msg varchar(100) null,
  description varchar(100) not null
  );


insert into tbl values
('hi', 'greet'),
(null, 'nothing');
```

And you do this expression:

```
select 'hulk' as x, msg, description 
from tbl where msg not in ('bruce','banner');
```

That will output 'hi' only.

The NOT IN is translated as:

```
select 'hulk' as x, msg, description 
from tbl where msg <> 'bruce' and msg <> 'banner';
```

`NULL <> 'bruce'` can't be determined, not even true, not even false

`NULL <> 'banner'` can't be determined, not even true not even false

So the null value expression, effectively resolved to:

```
can't be determined AND can't bedetermined
```

In fact, if your RDBMS supports boolean on SELECT(e.g. MySQL, Postgresql), you can see why: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/828

```
select null <> 'Bruce'
```

That returns null.

This returns null too:

```
select null <> 'Bruce' and null <> 'Banner'
```

Given you are using `NOT IN`, which is basically an AND expression.

```
NULL AND NULL
```

Results to NULL. So it's like you are doing a: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d5da/12

```
select * from tbl where null
```

Nothing will be returned

Comment: Yeah, I know there is a work around for this.I am just curious to know why is this strange behaviour?

Comment: It's not strange, it's even in ANSI SQL. Think of NULL as wildcard, you cannot assert that NULL <> 'Hello'; sometimes, NULL is meant to be substituted later on with real value. That's how I look at it. NULL has special meaning in database

Comment: And `IN` / `NOT IN`, is semantically equivalent to `V = 'Alpha' OR V = 'Beta'`, `V <> 'Alpha' AND V <> 'Beta'` respectively, hence the rules about NULL still applies

Comment: Thanks Michael Buen...I am using python with mysql.python returns 0/1 for AND,OR,IN statements but Mysql return NULL

Comment: Maybe the mistranslation lies on python's side. I'll check on language that supports nullable variable

Comment: I tried on ADO.NET, the `NULL <> 'Bruce'` resolves to System.DBNull, it's not 1 nor 0. Or maybe I'm using Postgres. I think it depends on the data access layer mechanism too. I would rather have a DAL that shows the same thing as what I can see on the RDBMS itself

Comment: the `case when` shortcut is genius

Comment: You made an excellent point. You say in your post: 
----------------
Error not in ('Timeout','Connection Error');

is semantically equivalent to:

Error <> 'TimeOut' AND Error <> 'Connection Error'

Rules about null comparison applies to IN too. So if the value of Error is NULL, the database can't make the expression true.
-----------------
And in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html  I found this sentence which confirms your statement: "If one or both arguments are NULL, the result of the comparison is NULL, except for the NULL-safe <=> equality comparison operator."

Answer (score 1):

Because null is undefined so null does not equal null. You always have to explicitly handle null.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` returns `NULL` if the expression on the left hand side is `NULL`. In order to get the `NULL` values, you have to do:

```
select count(*) from Table1 where CurrentDateTime>'2012-05-28 15:34:02.403504' and (Error not in ('Timeout','Connection Error') or Error is null);
```

Comment: Yeah, I have mentioned this is the question itself.I just wanted to know why this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

`IN` returns a trivalent `BOOLEAN` (which accepts `NULL` as a value). `NOT IN` returns the trivalent negation of `IN`, and negation of `NULL` is a `NULL`.

Imagine we have a table with all numbers from `1` to `1,000,000` in `id` and this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id IN (1, 2, NULL)
```

or its equivalent:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id = ANY
             (
             SELECT  1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT  2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT  NULL
             )
```

The predicate returns `TRUE` for `1` and `2` and `NULL` for all other values, so `1` and `2` are returned.

In its oppposite:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)
```

, or

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   id <> ALL
             (
             SELECT  1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT  2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT  NULL
             )
```

, the predicate returns `FALSE` for `1` and `2` and `NULL` for all other values, so nothing is returned.

Note that boolean negation not only changes the operator (`=` to `<>`), but the quantifier too (`ANY` to `ALL`).

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Buen ' s answer was the right answer for my case, but let me simplify why.

@Michael says in his post:

> ---
>
> Error not in ('Timeout','Connection Error');
>
> is semantically equivalent to:
>
> Error <> 'TimeOut' AND Error <> 'Connection Error'
>
> ### Rules about null comparison applies to IN too. So if the value of Error is NULL, the  database can't make the expression true.

And in [1] I found this sentence which confirms his most important statement for understanding why IN fails with NULL. In the specifications ("specs") in [1] you will: "If one or both arguments are NULL, the result of the comparison is NULL, except for the NULL-safe <=> equality comparison operator."

So yeah, the thing is that sadly Mysql gets lost in such a case. I think Mysql designers shouldn't have done this, because when I compare 2 to NULL, Mysql SHOULD be able to see they are DIFFERENT, and not simply throwing mistaken results. For example, I did:

```
select id from TABLE where id not in (COLUMN WITH NULLS);
```

then it throws EMPTY results. BUT. If I do

```
select id from TABLE where id not in (COLUMN WITH OUT NULLS);
```

it shows the right result. So when using the IN operator, you must filter out the NULLS. This is not a desired behavior for me as a user, but it's documented in the specifications in [1]. I think that languages and technology should be simpler, in the sense that you should be able to DEDUCE without the need of reading the specs. And truly, 2 is DIFFERENT from NULL, I should be the one in charge of controlling and taking care of mistakes of a higher level of abstraction, but MySQL SHOULD throw a FALSE result when comparing NULL  with a specific value.

References for the specs: [1]  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting twice in the same forum, but I want to illustrate another example:

I agree with @Wagner Bianchi in [2] in this forum when he says:
<< It’s very trick when dealing with data and subqueries>>

Moreover, this should NOT be the behavior, I think Mysql's designers are mistaken when they made this decision documented in [1]. The design should be different. Let me explain: You know that when comparing

```
select (2) not in (1, 4, 3);
    you will get:
        +----------------------+
        | (2) not in (1, 4, 3) |
        +----------------------+
        |                    1 |
        +----------------------+
        1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT if in the list you have at least one NULL then:

```
select (2) not in (1, NULL, 3);
    throws:
        +-------------------------+
        | (2) not in (1, NULL, 3) |
        +-------------------------+
        |                    NULL |
        +-------------------------+
        1 row in set (0.00 sec)
    This is pretty absurd.
```

We are not the first ones in getting confused by this. See [2]

References:

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

[2] http://blog.9minutesnooze.com/sql-not-in-subquery-null/comment-page-1/#comment-86954