# mysql 'IN' trouble when empty record

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql when i try :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score)
FROM DailyScore
WHERE team = '42'
AND Date IN('2013-08-01','2013-08-02','2013-08-03','2013-08-04')
```

It will return a result of :

```
50,100,75
```

Because team 42 has no score at '2013-08-02'

And I wish I can get :

```
50,,100,75
```

What sql query shall I use  ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why MYSQL IN keyword not considering NULL values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810391/why-mysql-in-keyword-not-considering-null-values)

Comment: I don't have time to type out some example code, but I think you'll find some good help in [this article](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator).

Answer (score 5):

If you mean that the score for `2013-08-02` is null then you should use `IFNULL`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(score, ''))
FROM DailyScore
WHERE team = '42'
AND Date IN('2013-08-01','2013-08-02','2013-08-03','2013-08-04')
```

If you mean there is not a record for `2013-08-02` for team `42`, you should look at using a [calendar table](http://crazycoders.net/2012/03/using-a-calendar-table-in-mysql/)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(score, ''))
FROM DailyScore
RIGHT JOIN Calendar ON Calendar.Date = DailyScore.Date
                   AND team = '42'
AND Calendar.Date IN('2013-08-01','2013-08-02','2013-08-03','2013-08-04')
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15825/9)

As a side note it seems like you could also use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(score, ''))
FROM DailyScore
WHERE team = '42'
AND Date BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-04'
```

Comment: +1 for multi - answer, but in matter of an fact, he needs something in the middle -` between` with `calendar table` to have best result

Comment: "calendar table" is a good reference. thx. 
the date is get from other query ,so a can't use "BETWEEN"

Comment: the query is not working. "team = '42'" should after the "ON" instead of after the "WHERE".

Comment: @TheoYmca yep you're right have updated my answer, alternatively you could do `WHERE team='42' OR team IS NULL` but I think the condition is better and more correct as part of the join clause.