# Mysql returns no values when null values are present In the subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do have two tables **table1** and **table2**. And their content as follows

```
mysql> select id from table1;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from table2;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|  301 |
|    2 |
| NULL |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

when I hit the below query in mysql console it always returns empty set

```
select id 
from table1 
where id 
not in (select id from table2);
```

**Empty set (0.00 sec)**

Is there a reason when there are null values in the sub query the **in** and **not in** would malfunction....?

I've solved it by using the below query

```
select id 
from table1 
where id 
not in (select id from table2 where id is not null);
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
```

**3 rows in set (0.00 sec)**

Just want to know

Thanks in advance :)

edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810391/why-mysql-in-keyword-not-considering-null-values) tries to clear some air but not enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why MYSQL IN keyword not considering NULL values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810391/why-mysql-in-keyword-not-considering-null-values)

Comment: Welcome to the world of *Three-Valued-Logic*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is how `not in` works.  I recommend that you use `not exists` instead:

```
select id 
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id);
```

Why does `not in` work this way?  It is because of the semantics of `not in`.  Remember that `NULL` in SQL (usually) means an *unknown* value.  Hence, if you have a list of "(1, 2)" you can say that "3" is not in the list.  If you have "(1, 2, *unknown*)" you cannot say that.  Instead, the result is `NULL`, which is treated as false.

`NOT EXISTS` does not behave this way, so I find it more convenient to use.