# PHP CI sql query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need some help with a query as I don't seem to get my head around it.

First table vacancies:

```
vac_id
vac_title
vac_location
vac_description
is_deleted
status
```

Second table vacancies_labels:

```
vac_id
Label_id
```

Now I would like to get an output containing all vacancies within a certain location but they also cannot contain the label_id '10' nonetheless of the location.

```
SELECT `v`.*
FROM `vacancies` AS `v`
LEFT JOIN `vacancies_labels` as `vl` ON `v`.`vacancy_id` = `bl`.`vacancy_id`
WHERE `v`.`vac_location` = 'russia'
AND `v`.`is_deleted` != 1
AND `v`.`status` = 1
AND `vl`.`label_id` NOT IN ('10')
GROUP BY `v`.`vacancy_id`
```

This results only in the vacancies that have a record in the vacancies_labels table that are not 10. It leaves out however all vacancies that have no records at all in the vacancies_labels table but fit within the location range.

What am I missing here?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a LEFT JOIN, if the record is not found, then the values will return null.  But in your WHERE clause, you have

```
AND `vl`.`label_id` NOT IN ('10')
```

as `NOT IN` [doesn't consider nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810391/why-mysql-in-keyword-not-considering-null-values) you have to do something like...

```
AND ( `vl`.`label_id` NOT IN ('10') OR `vl`.`label_id` IS NULL)
```

Comment: AND ( `vl`.`label_id` NOT IN ('10') **AND** `vl`.`label_id` IS **NOT** NULL) ? Now you select when there is no label_id ?

Comment: @splash58 I thought *It leaves out however all vacancies that have no records* means they want the records when it is null.

Comment: I think OP want records having label. Else, you are right

Comment: Nigel is correct in his thinking, not all vacancies have labels but my code skips them because like he explained with the nulls