# MySQL multiple columns in IN clause with null values

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

I want to query over two columns as **2-tuples** , where one  can be null.

**example :**

```
    +-------------------------+
    |   first    |     last   |
    +-------------------------+
    |   Homer    |     NULL   |
    |   Marge    |    Simpson |
    +-------------------------+
```

Something like:

```
Select * from cartoons where (first, last ) in ((Homer ,NULL  ), ( Marge ,Simpson) ) ;
```

(Which should retrieve both Homer's and Marge's rows)

I am using the following query for test:

```
select  ('Homer', null)  in (('Homer',  null));
```

which returns null.

Reference to related questions :

- [MySQL multiple columns in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706196/mysql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause)
- [Why MYSQL IN keyword not considering NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810391/why-mysql-in-keyword-not-considering-null-values)

SQL version : 5.7.12

Comment: why don't change those null value with `IFNULL()` to avoid null problem? or is there any limitation so you can't change the data at all?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: added to question

Comment: Try: select  ('Homer', coalesce(null, 'null'))  in (('Homer',  coalesce(null, 'null')));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the tuple syntax in this case, which uses equality comparisons under the hood.  Instead, use the longer version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cartoons
WHERE first = 'Homer' AND last IS NULL OR first = 'Marge' AND last = 'Simpson';
```

Just for reference, here is what your current query is actually saying:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cartoons
WHERE first = 'Homer' AND last = NULL OR first = 'Marge' AND last = 'Simpson';
```

Note that comparing a column directly to `NULL` is semantically incorrect.

Comment: Thank u for your answer . In my real life use case Im getting a long array of these 2-tuples  . So writing this as a very long query is really not optimal solution .

Comment: You need parentheses

Comment: @Strawberry You need to re-read the precedence rules of SQL.  `AND` has greater precedence than `OR`, so the logic as already written above is correct.

Comment: I can see this going very wrong very quickly

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT * FROM cartoons WHERE (first in (Array1)  AND last IS NULL) OR (last in (Array2)  AND first IS NULL) OR (first in (Array1)  AND last in (Array2));
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer . But tough very creative this isn't  equivalent to  searching by tuples . Since a  ('Marge' , null)    tuple would also be part of the result set .

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM cartoons 
JOIN ( SELECT 'Homer' first, NULL last
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Marge', 'Simpson' ) criteria ON cartoons.first <=> criteria.first
                                           AND cartoons.last  <=> criteria.last
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULL`-safe comparisons, which in MySQL uses `<=>`. Assuming that only the second column can be NULL:

```
Select c.*
from cartoons c
where (first = 'Homer' and last <=> NULL) or
      (first = 'Marge' and last <=> 'Simpson')\;
```