# MySQL 'NOT IN' returns empty result even when there is no match

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is:

```
Tree table:
+----+------+
| id | p_id |
+----+------+
| 1  | null |
| 2  | 1    |
| 3  | 1    |
| 4  | 2    |
| 5  | 2    |
+----+------+
```

If I execute

```
SELECT id FROM Tree
WHERE id IN (SELECT p_id FROM Tree)
```

I get the expected answer

```
+----+
| id | 
+----+
| 1  | 
| 2  | 
+----+
```

However, if I execute

```
SELECT id FROM Tree
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT p_id FROM Tree)
```

I get an empty result:

```
+----+
| id | 
+----+ 
+----+
```

instead of the expected 3, 4, 5. As far as I understand, `NOT IN` should give the complementary set given by `IN` (excluding `NULL`s)?

New to SQL, sorry if I'm missing something basic.

Comment: It's working correctly. There are a null/missing values in the table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810391/why-mysql-in-keyword-not-considering-null-values

Answer (score 4):

Nulls represent missing but **existing** data. Therefore the engine can't really decide if a row is not in the set when it doesn't find a clear match. As a result `NOT IN` will produce no rows in the presence of nulls.

Anyway, you can use an anti-join to get the result you want. For example:

```
select a.id
from tree a
left join tree b on b.p_id = a.id
where b.p_id is null
```

Alternatively, you can use `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: The engine can decide if a value is in the list, but it cannot decide if something is not in the list if the list contains a null (because something = null or something = something is decidably true, while something = null or something = something_else is not decidable and thus unknown (null), and not (unknown) is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you could use `NOT EXIST` which takes in consideration NULLS, while IN operator doesn't

```
SELECT id FROM Tree
WHERE  NOT exists (SELECT 1 FROM Tree t1 where t1.p_id=Tree.id) ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fff39bf4a29193a8eb9644b9c126771b